# Redirect all request from http://example.com to https://example.com while exempting http://example.com/api

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site www.example.com which has an api endpoint of https://example.com/api.

We recently installed an ssl certificate on the server. 
We want all website traffic from http://www.example.com, www.example.com, https://example.com to be redirected to https://www.example.com but we don't want request coming from https://example.com/api to be redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Check this rule in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer, gladly appreciated.
Unfortunately we review the question and hence i refine the question.